# Gamecenter Facebook Like Execution from App

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch, game-center

Im looking for simple way to put Like Button into my SkScene, But the Like button from my gamecenter  App. Is There any function which i could call to execute Like my game on gamecenter and check if the   button was already liked?

Answer (score 0):

It's a preview though, so be careful https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/

Comment: There is any simpler way to just Like my game on Gamecenter ? Any callback to "Like" in gamecenter. Or just check if the game was liked on gamecenter?

Comment: You need to check Facebook like API for that

Comment: But how to refer to gamecenter facebook like, gamecenter like is not typical facebook page like. It's generate itunes link which was liked. Any ideas?